# Leaflet-map click event not emitted when layer controls moved out of map-element

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

I have a problem with Leaflet-map's click-event.

I moved Layers-control out of map-element like this:

```
document.getElementById('outside-controls').appendChild(ctrl.getContainer());
```

After that I started to miss click-event every time I change layers-control setup.

Here is working sample code:

```
var dom_documentClicks = document.getElementById('document-clicks'),
    dom_mapClicks = document.getElementById('map-clicks'),
    count_documentClicks = 0,
    count_mapClicks = 0;

var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: osmAttrib
    }),
    poly = L.polygon([]),
    ctrl = L.control.layers({}, {'Polygon Layer': poly}, {collapsed: false});

// initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
var map = L.map('map', {layers: [osm, poly]}).setView([61.497752, 23.760954], 12);

ctrl.addTo(map);

// This seems to be the reason why click-event is not emitted.
document.getElementById('outside-controls').appendChild(ctrl.getContainer());


function onDocumentClick(e) {
  count_documentClicks++;
  dom_documentClicks.innerHTML = count_documentClicks;
}

function onMapClick(e) {
  count_mapClicks++;
  dom_mapClicks.innerHTML = count_mapClicks;
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick);
```

And link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/135/

**Anyone who knows a way to get rid of this issue (bug?)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ctrl.getContainer() returns div that consumes next click-event from map.

when changing this:

```
ctrl.getContainer()
```

to this:

```
ctrl.getContainer().childNodes[0]
```

it works!